# How to delete parent object without delete the child object?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

How can I delete the parent object without deleting child object in Hibernate? In my case a child has multiple parents. I just want to remove one parent object from child object.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, though you must remember about two things:

**1)** Your child entity must allow null on the foreign key to the child

**2)** You must remember to NOT have CascadeType.DELETE on the @OneToMany relationship in the parent.

**3)** Before removing the parent, clear the children collection first:

```
parent.setChildren(null);
session.delete(parent);
```

Comment: any luck with the tests?

Comment: This will not work. You have to fo through all the children and set **their** parent null and not the other way around.